# How do the new Jenkins build strategies interact with "skip" strategies

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm having trouble understanding how the newer Branch API [Basic Branch Build Strategies](https://github.com/jenkinsci/basic-branch-build-strategies-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc) interact with each other.

What I'd really like is to understand how to understand and craft rules - but for now I'm happy to solve a concrete example:

What I'd like to get is:

- Build all branches selected by the SCM rules (Regular Branches), but skip initial builds on branch discovery
- Build all pull requests (change requests) selected by the SCM rules
- Allow commit messages with a "skip pattern" to skip building a particular change (in a pull request or on a branch)

The building blocks from the [Basic Branch Build Strategies](https://github.com/jenkinsci/basic-branch-build-strategies-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc) seem like a good match at first blush - we have:

1. Change requests
2. Regular Branches (or I could use named branches by regexp/wildcard)
3. "Skip build trigger if commit message contains" to skip by regexp from messages
4. "Skip Initial build on first branch indexing"

However when all of these are added neither of the skip rules seem to take effect.  This could make some sense if the combined strategies are "logically or'ed".  Every build candidate is a branch and/or a pull-request so they already match

So an alternative is to combine using the "All strategies match" and "Any strategies match".

1. All Strategies Match

   1. Any Strategies Match

      1. Regular branches
      2. Change requests
   2. Skip build on message
   3. Skip build on first commit

Now my pull-requests don't build automatically.

I suspect with enough levels of "Any" and "All" I might be able to get something right, but it seems complicated.

Additionally the "Skip" strategies are unclear on how they interact with the "All" filter - since they are negative.

Even more confusingly the individual strategies can be re-ordered - although by default they seem to have a preferred order.  I can't see how that interacts through "All", "Any" or just the top-level list.

Can anyone clarify how these strategies interact?  I have found no relevant documentation.